# Need some help about decompiling python bytecode

Tags: python, bytecode

```
432         134 SETUP_FINALLY           14 (to 150)

433         136 LOAD_FAST                8 (contract)
            138 LOAD_METHOD             11 (decode_function_input)
            140 LOAD_FAST                7 (input_bytes)
            142 CALL_METHOD              1
            144 STORE_FAST               9 (decoded)
            146 POP_BLOCK
            148 JUMP_FORWARD            56 (to 206)

435     >>  150 DUP_TOP
            152 LOAD_GLOBAL             12 (ValueError)
            154 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
            156 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE      204
            158 POP_TOP
            160 STORE_FAST              10 (ve)
            162 POP_TOP
            164 SETUP_FINALLY           26 (to 192)

436         166 LOAD_GLOBAL             13 (logging)
            168 LOAD_METHOD             14 (exception)
            170 LOAD_FAST               10 (ve)
            172 CALL_METHOD              1
            174 POP_TOP

437         176 POP_BLOCK
            178 POP_EXCEPT
            180 CALL_FINALLY            10 (to 192)
            182 POP_TOP
            184 EXTENDED_ARG             3
            186 JUMP_ABSOLUTE         1002
            188 POP_BLOCK
            190 BEGIN_FINALLY
        >>  192 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            194 STORE_FAST              10 (ve)
            196 DELETE_FAST             10 (ve)
            198 END_FINALLY
            200 POP_EXCEPT
            202 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 206)
        >>  204 END_FINALLY
```

I'm trying to decompile this bytecode to source code but i failed

```
    <SETUP_FINALLY(14,to 150)>
    decoded=contract.decode_function_input(input_bytes)
    <POP_BLOCK(None,None)>
            ve=elif (<DUP_TOP(None,None)>)exception matchValueError:
            <SETUP_FINALLY(26,to 192)>
            logging.exception(ve)
            <POP_BLOCK(None,None)>
            <POP_EXCEPT(None,None)>
            <CALL_FINALLY(10,to 192)>
            <POP_BLOCK(None,None)>
            <BEGIN_FINALLY(None,None)>
            ve=None
            <DELETE_FAST(10,ve)>
            <END_FINALLY(None,None)>
            <POP_EXCEPT(None,None)>
    else:
            <END_FINALLY(None,None)>
```

Comment: Could you provide more details ?

Comment: I am trying to decompile it manually, because there are some python bytecode decompilers available on github but they are not working.

Comment: What's giving you trouble?

Comment: SETUP_FINALLY, CALL_FINALLY, END_FINALLY these operations are the problem. I did not understand them. I am trying to decompile them manually but need some help.

Comment: The documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html